# Keras shape error in applications Inception Resnet v2

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I'm using Keras 2.1.3 and I'm trying to fine tune a Inception Resnetv2 with Keras application.

So I load the pretrained model from keras.applications

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(299,299,3))
model = applications.inception_resnet_v2.InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', 
                                                        include_top=False,
                                                        input_tensor=input_tensor,
                                                        input_shape=(299, 299,3))
```

I create the bottleneck for my problem :

```
top_model = Sequential()
top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))
top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
top_model.add(Dense(40, activation='softmax'))
```

And finally create a new model to concatenate the two parts :

```
new_model = Sequential()
for l in model.layers:
      new_model.add(l)
```

At this step, I got an error

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_7: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 192 but got shape (None, 35, 35, 64)

So I printed each layer shape and I have

> Layer n-1 : Input : (None, 35, 35, 64), Output : (None, 35, 35, 64)
>
> Layer n : Input : (None, 35, 35, 192), Output : (None, 35, 35, 48)

As you can see shapes dismatch and it seems weird that come from Keras.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/27796/8560, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/27796/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure `top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=model.output_shape[1:]))` is passing the required dimensions.
An alternative way would be to try.

```
ResNetV2_model_output = model.output
new_concatenated_model = Flatten()(ResNetV2_model_output)
new_concatenated_model = (Dense(256, activation='relu'))(new_concatenated_model)
new_concatenated_model = ((Dropout(0.5)))(new_concatenated_model)
new_concatenated_model = (Dense(40, activation='softmax'))(new_concatenated_model)
```

Comment: I don't understand good your alternative, **new_concatenated_model** has to be a new **Sequential** ? And then add the new layer ?

Comment: But my error seems to come from early layer (~ 21-22th) so I don't think the problem come from the new top model.

Comment: You can choose to add layers on the model without Sequential, this option enables you to start from there and add on custom layers.

Comment: I tried your solution but I don't get what is my model, when I print **new_concatenated_model** I have **keras.layers.core.Dense** and i can't iterate on layers or compile it.

Comment: My bad edited the code the other operations weren't being applied to "new_concatenated_model"

Comment: So **new_concatenated_model** is a **tf.Tensor**, can I use it or should I rebuild a model ?

Comment: Yes it is a tensor and you can use it

Comment: Ok, I did **model2 = keras.Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=new_concatenated_model)** and it seems to be a valid model, is this the right practice?

Comment: Forgive me there l am a bit uncertain if it the one you suggested or **model2 =keras.Model(inputs=input_tesnsor.input, outputs=new_concatenated_model)**. but definitely one of the two variants is correct.

Comment: Ok model2 = keras.Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=new_concatenated_model) and model2 = keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=new_concatenated_model) work, thanks for your answers.

Comment: My pleasure now go rule the world ;]